# Close Bootstrap Menu when a Link is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a side menu that displays offcanvas.  When you click the button, the canvas pushes left and opens the menu.  I would like the menu to collapse and not remain open when a link is selected.

Here is the HTMl:

```
<header>
        <nav class="menu" id="theMenu" ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
          <div class="menu-wrap">
            <a ng-href="/"><img src="/images/zj-logo.png" alt="Zach Janice" class="logo"></a>
            <i class="fa fa-times menu-close"></i>
            <a ng-href="/">Home</a>
            <a ng-href="#/about">About</a>
            <a ng-href="#/projects">Projects</a>
            <a ng-href="#/services">Services</a>
            <a ng-href="#/contact">Contact</a>
          </div><!-- menu-wrap -->
          <div id="menuToggle" class="active">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </div><!-- menuToggle -->
        </nav>
      </header>
```

jQuery:

```
(function(jQuery){

            // Menu settings
            jQuery('#menuToggle, .menu-close').on('click', function(){
                jQuery('#menuToggle').toggleClass('active');
                jQuery('body').toggleClass('body-push-toleft');
                jQuery('#theMenu').toggleClass('menu-open');
            });


        })(jQuery);
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

-Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `toggleClass`, you can just add `.menu-wrap a` to your selector which should toggle it off when clicked. The links won't be in view unless the classes are added, so you won't get any mis-clicks.

```
jQuery('#menuToggle, .menu-close', '.menu-wrap a').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('#menuToggle').toggleClass('active');
    jQuery('body').toggleClass('body-push-toleft');
    jQuery('#theMenu').toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```

Comment: I knew it was something easy, just brain dead before a long weekend.  Thanx Ben, very much appreciated.